# Warning: session_destroy()?

Tags: php, session

Im trying to fix my login script, on my localhost it works but uploaded to my online test server, the logout is broken, I get this error:

```
Warning: session_destroy() [function.session-destroy]: Trying to destroy uninitialized session in htdocs/logout.php on line 17

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at htdocs/logout.php:17) in htdocs/logout.php on line 18

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at htdocs/logout.php:17) in www/htdocs/logout.php on line 34
```

Not quite sure what could be causing it since it was working on my localhost, any ideas?

Comment: Could you show the code of logout.php?

Comment: Is there any output before session_destroy?

Also, what is the PHP reporting level in localhost. If it's set to ignore warnings, then it's just not showing those messages.

Comment: Hi check there any out put has displayed as header and before doing the session_destroy you shoud start the session on php gud luck

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
session_start();
session_destroy(); /*or sesion_unset();*/
```

Comment: That worked :) thanks, any reason why it would work on my localhost even without `session_start()`?

Comment: perhaps you have used error_reporting(0) which forces to hide error or have setting in PHP.INI to automatically start session in all page ! or have included a page where you have started session !

Comment: Got it thanks :), btw I saw your ultra light forums link, you have a typo in there it says "can reply to uther's topic." **Author

Answer (score 6):

For [session_destroy](http://nl2.php.net/session_destroy) to work, session has to be started using [session_start](http://nl2.php.net/session_start).

Comment: That worked :) thanks, any reason why it would work on my localhost even without `session_start()`???

Comment: You can also use the session.auto_start configuration directive

Answer (score 3):

If you need to just delete the session if it exists (for example in an auto called exit/logout/destructor script) and it may or may not exist, then you can use session_status to check the status.

As of PHP 5.4.0, you can check it like this:

```
if(session_status() == PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE)
{
    session_destroy();
}
```

This is preferable to creating a new section just to destroy it later.

Per the PHP manual, session_status will return an integer that can be compared with the following constants:

```
Return Values 

• PHP_SESSION_DISABLED - Returned if sessions are disabled. 
• PHP_SESSION_NONE - Returned if sessions are enabled, but none exists. 
• PHP_SESSION_ACTIVE - Returned if sessions are enabled, and one exists.
```

This allows you to write better, more efficient, and more flexible session management code.